# How can I regain access to MS SQL Server after default database for a user is taken offline?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, offline

### Act in haste...

In the process of off-lining a database for backup I lost connection, the only user I had details for was set to use the database which I had just off-lined (thankfully not the `master` database) as the default database...problem as you can see.

In looking about on stack overflow I was unable to find a solution for my problem.

After a bit of digging about I remembered the command-line tool `sqlcmd`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Repent at leisure:

Well the solution to the problem was pretty straightforward:

- Open up a command-line ( `Start->Run->cmd` then hit `Enter`)
- In the command-line type the following (substituting correct values where needed)

  - `sqlcmd -S myserver\sqlexpress -d master -U myusername -P mypassword`  which starts a command-line connection to the database specified after `-d`
  - **Note**: ensure the switches are typed as above as unusually MS actually bothered with case sensitivity, so `-s/-S`, `-d/-D`, `-u/-U` and `-p/-P` are **not** interchangeable.
- once the connection to the database is established the window will display a connection prompt similar to:[image: logged in sqlcmd prompt]
- Once you have the correct prompt, type the following in:

  - `alter login myusernamehere with default_database = master` to set the default database for your user to master
  - On the next line type `go` and press `enter` . . . and that should be your user set to using the `master` database as its default database to connect to.  It should appear on-screen to look like this: [image: alter default database for user]
- Now you can connect with MS SQL Server Management Studio as normal and get the lovely graphical interface to use for your database admin tasks.
- Carry out your management tasks and bring the database back on-line as you need/see fit
- Set the default database for your user back to the database you have just brought back online, by changing the name of the database in the previous command to the name of the database you just brought back on-line, looking something like: [image: restore default database for the user to the database it used to be]

And that should be you set.  I know this is an unlikely scenario for most, but should it happen to you, hopefully this will be of some use in restoring your normal access and getting the database back on-line.

Answer (score 5):

The other option is to click the "Options" button when logging into SSMS.  There, you can specify which database to connect to.  So as long as you have access to one of the other databases, such as master, you should be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this simply illustrates how my historical use of computers precluded a UI answer: I was not even aware of this option and defaulted to a low level shell-based approach.  For many people this will be an invaluable option :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks GMasucci, great answer. 
I am using windows account, here is what i did.

```
sqlcmd -d master
```

then

```
alter login [domain\myName] with default_database = master
go
quit
```